# Update Gridview when in Edit mode

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net form.

It loads a grid view with 30 columns and data from a sql server table.

Curently I can Double click to edit any row. 
I can Tab to move to the next column during edit.

but i must scroll or tab all the way to the right and click update to confirm the udpdate.

What I want to happen is when I tap "Enter/return", is for the the whole row to be updated (updated in the database).

On my OnRowDatabound code i have the following (please feel free to offer suggestions if it is incorrect completely)

```
     Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        e.Row.Attributes("style") = "cursor:pointer"
        e.Row.Attributes("ondblclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Edit$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
'following code blatently stolen from the web and converted to vb.net and attenmpte to solve the javascript element
        If (e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit) OrElse (e.Row.RowState = (DataControlRowState.Edit Or DataControlRowState.Alternate)) Then
            e.Row.Cells(0).Width = Unit.Pixel(35)
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) { __doPostBack('" & "Update$" + GridView1.EditIndex.ToString() & "'); return false; }")
     End If
     End Sub
```

I have insufficient knowledge of javascript to see where i am going wrong in the last line of the if statement.

I could also be wishful thinking that this will give the solution i want. All asp.net solutions around gridview seem to be in C# which if i need to, i will get my hands dirty.

Comment: The first arg of `__doPostBack` should be a control; the 2nd arg is anything else you need to add. I don't remember the internals of this but it might be difficult, because without any changes, each button knows which row it's with. Getting a single action (Enter) to know which row to deal with is...not sure it's possible. I think this might have been asked before though. Make sure you search, online too.

Comment: One thing you can do is move the edit button. Go into the markup and move `<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />` to any column you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just playing with a gridview. When the Update and Cancel buttons are showing you can view the html source.

This is what I got when editing the first row:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$ctl00','')">Update</a>
```

This is what I got when editing the second row:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl03$ctl00','')">Update</a>
```

If you can figure out which row is being edited, it looks like you could do this with plain javascript on the page, just copy the js that is injected into the grid.

In the first row it's `ctl02`; in the second row it's `ctl03`. There's a header on my grid which is probably why the controls start at 2.

You might be able to just do a loop and see if a control exists. The html-with-javascript for an update button will only exist if update has been clicked.

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your time and effort in responding to me. Thanks to you identifying that i need to know where in the gridview i am before i can confirm the edit it led me to review my code.

From here i re-examined some c# code i was using as a guide (but want it to be in vb.net).

Here is my solution

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        e.Row.Attributes("style") = "cursor:pointer"
        e.Row.Attributes("ondblclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Edit$" & e.Row.RowIndex)

        Dim js As String = "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) { __doPostBack('" + GridView1.UniqueID + "', 'Update$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + "'); return false; }"
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", js)

End Sub
```

The `Gridview1.UniqueID` was missing from the javascript element.

I have tested this and it is working.

Thanks again @Wazz, I am marking yours as the answer as it helped me to solve my issue.